# Dado un array de enteros encontrar los numeros que suman 10, con programación funcional

Tags: java-8

Estoy tratando de pasar este ejercicio de programación imperativa a programación funcional con stream(), alguien tiene idea de como hacerlo.

```
int[] arrayNumber = new int[]{1, 2, 3, 7};

    for (int i = 0; i < arrayNumber.length ; i++) {
        for (int j = i + 1; j < arrayNumber.length; j++) {
            if(arrayNumber[i] + arrayNumber[j] == 10){
               System.out.println(arrayNumber[i] + " " + arrayNumber[j]);
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Puedes intentar sustiuir los ciclos `for` por `IntStream`s. Quedaría:

```java
IntStream.range(0, arrayNumber.length)
    .forEach(i -> IntStream.range(i + 1, arrayNumber.length)
        .filter(j -> arrayNumber[j] + arrayNumber[i] == 10)
        .forEach(j -> System.out.println(arrayNumber[i] + " " + arrayNumber[j])));
```

De cualquier manera, fuera de lo académico, no le veo beneficio a usar programación funcional en este caso específico. A mi entender, queda un poco menos legible.